# Graphical glitch causes workspace switcher screen to be too large on my account

Tags: unity, compiz, workspaces

When I press Super+S to switch workspaces, the switcher doesn't expand far enough, so the workspaces aren't fully visible:

[image]

Notice how the top orange bar is not showing. The bottom one is also not showing when the bottom workspaces are selected.

It looks as expected in the guest account.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open CompizConfig Setting Manager (`ccsm`)
2. Desktop → Expo → Appearance
3. Increase `Y Offset`

[image: Compiz Expo Offsets]